# How to use condition for custom post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I make a custom post named portfolio-items. I want to use this in a condition. like that if there is any portfolio-items then it will show the items. otherwise it will show default data.
Its for showing a user that here can enter portfolio.I make all the things and can enter data from admin panel. But cannot understand how to set the condition.

How to do this?please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you create single-portfolio-items.php in your theme directory? It'll automatically redirect to post_type separate page. You can customize it accordingly.

Comment: thanks. ya I can. But I think you didnot get my question. I want that if I add any portfolio item it will show in my pages. like the screenshot http://s16.postimg.org/ys0na0ic5/screenshot_186.jpg. or If there is no item in this it shows me a blank portion. thats why I want to set here a default data that a user can understand here is the portfolio section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this function

```
function get_portfolio(){

global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='portfolio-items'", OBJECT ); 

return $result ;
}
```

If `$result` is not empty then you have portfolio-items. This makes the condition.